# Getting No route matches [POST] when using turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have todo list app. In the application there are multiple places wher you can mark a todo done by clicking in a checkbox.

This is the erb

```
<% @todos.each do |todo|%>
 <%= form_for todo, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :completed, :class => "dashboard_done_box", :id => todo.id %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and here's the js

```
$(document).on('click', ".dashboard_done_box", function(){
 $("#edit_todo_" + $(this).attr('id')).submit()
});
```

The routes.rb has the line

```
resources :todos
```

When I refresh the page it works, but when I am navigating to it I get this error.

```
Started POST "/todos/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-07 13:18:45 +0200
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/todos/1"):
```

It also works when I disable **turbolinks**.

This code works on other pages in my application it is just on one page I have this problem.

When it works in makes a PATCH request

```
Started PATCH "/todos/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-07 13:44:08 +0200
Processing by TodosController#update as JS
```

Why does it do a POST request and how is it connected to turbolinks?

**Update**

Yosep Kim suggested I should make a post route

routes.rb

```
post 'todos/:id'  => 'todos#update', :as => :todo_update
```

The form

```
<%= form_for @todo, remote: true, url: todo_update_path(@todo), method: :post do |f| %>
```

Now I get trough to the controller, but only with these parameters

```
{"controller"=>"todos", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"3"}
```

Conclusion: The form submission is not getting serialized. Why?

Comment: Are you missing `@todo` in `form_for` or its supposed to be like this? Post your `controller code` and `Routes`.

Comment: It is just a part of a loop. I added it to avoid confusion. The relevant route is there. The problem is that it never hits the controller so the controller code is irrelevant.

Comment: I think changing the method to post may work `method: :post`

Comment: @Pavan Nope. That gives me the error in all use cases.

Comment: Might it be, due to turbolinks not recompiling the javascript but re-rendering the body, that the auto-magical rails-ajax javascript's connection to your form gets some corrupt data?

Comment: @Nicolay Yes, but why and how ; )

Comment: If you put a debug statement in your javascript (in the event handler), what is the result you get when you inspect `$('edit_todo_'+$(this).attr('id'))`? Are the properties you want to submit all there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does the form render?

Rails uses the PATCH verb to update because in rails applications a update is almost always a partial update. The PUT verb should be used for complete updates ( like when you overwrite a file )  Read more here [Riding With Rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/)

Rails uses hidden fields to accommodate the html verb.

Your form should render like this

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/todos/5" class="edit_todo" data-remote="true" id="roster_edit_done_todo_5" method="post">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">
  </div>
 <!-- What ever fields you need -->
</form>
```

Be aware if you have the form in a table. The table might make the form render strange.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The form_for call was a result of one of my experiments. I did the` method: :patch` to try to force the rails patch trick. But, it does not work. Neither does   `<%= form_for todo, remote: true do |f| %>`

Comment: So when you submit the `<%= form_for todo, remote: true do |f| %>` form, what is the url and method which comes through?

Comment: it's `Started POST "/todos/1"`, should be `Started PATCH "/todos/1"`. I've updated the question

Comment: I'd expect it to do a PUT to "/todos/1" - that's odd.  I don't know what the "rails patch trick" is.  You might be referring to the same "_method" trick i was in my answer.  Is there a hidden field in the form with a "_method" param?

Comment: Yes it is the same trick. Rails uses the PATCH verb to update because in rails applications a update is almost always a partial update. The PUT verb should be used for complete updates ( like when you overwrite a file )  [Riding With Rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/)

Comment: I see.  So, is that hidden field included in the form, when it renders onto the page?

Comment: Thanks! That was the question I needed. I'll edit your answer and accept it.

Comment: thanks, but you didn't so much edit my answer as delete it and rewrite it from scratch, which is a bit of an odd thing to do...

Comment: Look at it as a suggestion. Edit what you don't like. I just made a PUT request instead of a PATCH ;)

Comment: You totally changed all the content!  I'm not complaining, and i'm not going to go back and edit it.  I'm just saying it's a very odd thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug on latest 64bit Chrome dev/beta channel version 37,38.

If you use it, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388664

Comment: That's the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is creating two redundant requests, when the checkbox is clicked. The first one is fired by the form, and the second by the JS code you have. The one that is fired by the form would ONLY work one time after the page refreshes. Once you click on it, Turbolink would refresh the contents in the BODY without reloading the DOM, failing to attach the AJAX event handler to the form.

You can suppress the default behavior by using preventDefault. This should only fire the action once through the JS code.

```
$(document).on('click', ".dashboard_done_box", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#edit_todo_" + $(this).attr('id')).submit()
});
```

Comment: Thnaks for your time! It does not solve the problem. It behaves like before.

Comment: No problem. It looks like the JS is creating a POST request, while your server is set up to handle POST request to the resource. Maybe, you can change it to accept the POST as well.